# Counterexample for ${\rm Hom}_{R}(\prod_{i\in I}M_{i},N)\cong_{\mathbb{Z}} \coprod_{i\in I}{\rm Hom}_{R}(M_{i},N)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $\{M_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of $R$-modules and also $N$ is a $R$-module. Is there an counterexample for the following relation: 
  ${\rm Hom}_{R}(\prod_{i\in I}M_{i},N)\cong_{\mathbb{Z}} \coprod_{i\in I}{\rm Hom}_{R}(M_{i},N).$

Comment: If by $\coprod$ you mean the category-theoretic coproduct, then to find a counterexample you will have to take $I$ infinite. If you mean the set-theoretic disjoint union, then there are lots of trivial counterexamples: for example, take $N = 0$...

Comment: @ZhenLin  $\coprod$ mean that the category-theoretic coproduct,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $R=k$ a field, $I$ any infinite set, $M_i = k$ for each $i$, and $N=k$. Then the left hand side is the dual of $k^I$, which has dimension strictly greater than the cardinal of $I$, whereas the right hand side is the direct sum of $I$ copies of the dual of $k$, which has dimension the cardinal of $I$.